# MVC change input value from Javascript during Form Submit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model, form-submit

Need to change the user input right before going to the controller after form submit. The below solution changes the value but **Modified input showing on the HTML Input field after replacing it from JavaScript.**

Need alternative approach to change the value at Model level; therefore, the user cannot see the supplied input is changing.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("#submitButton").click(function (event) {
        var element = document.getElementById("RawHtml");
        var val = document.getElementById("RawHtml").value;
        document.getElementById("RawHtml").value = val.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
     });
});
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="field">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RawHtml)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.RawHtml)
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="submitButton" />
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below:

If you don't want user to know that the supplied input is changed and then passed then change the supplied input when it hits the controller ActionResult.

Example:

```
[POST]
public ActionResult Demo(ModelName model){
    string finalHtml= model.RawHtml.Replace("value to be replaced","replacement value for existing value");
    //further use finalHtml to store in DB
}
```